# web rtc dataChannels not working no connection establishing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, node.js, webrtc

My create offer code is below. When I try to connect two remote peers it doesn't connect nor `datachannel.onopen` event runs and shows the connection opened. I am having lots of trouble in learning about this

```js
let peerConfigs = {
    iceServers: [{
        urls: ['stun:stun1.1.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302']
    }]
}

let peerConnection;
let userlist = document.querySelector('ul');
let li;
let sendingToUser;
let fromUser;
let localStream;
let remoteStream;
let dataChannel;

const callBtn = document.getElementById('call');
const joinBtn = document.getElementById('join-btn');
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

const sendToUsers = [
    "shubhamkumarin2022@gmail.com",
    "jatinder2022@gmail.com",
]

const fromUsers = [
    "shubhamkumarin2022@gmail.com",
    "jatinder2022@gmail.com",
]

const addUser = async () => {
    socket.emit('user:join', { email: fromUser })
}

joinBtn.addEventListener('click', addUser)

sendToUsers.map((user) => {
    li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerHTML = user
    li.addEventListener('click', () => {
        sendingToUser = user
    })

    userlist.appendChild(li);
});

fromUsers.map((user) => {
    li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerHTML = user
    li.addEventListener('click', () => {
        fromUser = user
    })

    userlist.appendChild(li);
});


const createOffer = async (e) => {
    try {
        console.log(sendingToUser, 'sendingto');
        console.log(sendingToUser, fromUser);

        peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [{
                urls: ['stun:stun1.1.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302']
            }]
        });

        dataChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel("channel", {
            reliable: true
        })

        let offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
        peerConnection.onicecandidate = (e) => {
            if (e.candidate) {
                console.log("candiddate repinting", peerConnection.localDescription)
            }
        }

        dataChannel.onerror = (err) => console.log(err)
        dataChannel.onmessage = (e) => {
            console.log("message arrived", e.data)
        }

        dataChannel.onopen = (e) => {
            console.log("connection opened");
            dataChannel.send("heheheheheheheh");
        }

        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        socket.emit('making:call', { to: sendingToUser, from: fromUser, offer })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

callBtn.addEventListener('click', createOffer)
```

Here I am setting my remote peer sessions description as no but everything seems alright to me still no connection is being established between the peers so that I can start exchanging messages

`ondatachannel` event handler not even showing a message of connection opened. help

```js
 const handleIncomingCall = async (data) => {
    try {
        const { from, offer } = data
        peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [{
                urls: ['stun:stun1.1.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302']
            }]
        });

        peerConnection.onicecandidate = (e) => {
            if (e.candidate) {
                console.log("candiggggdate repinting", peerConnection.localDescription)
            }
        }

        peerConnection.ondatachannel = (e) => {
            console.log('handle incomig on data channe;')
            peerConnection.dc = e.channel
            peerConnection.dc.onmessage = (e) => {
                console.log("new message arrived", e.data)
            }

            peerConnection.dc.onopen = () => {
                console.log("data channel")
            }

            peerConnection.dc.onerror = (err) => {
                console.log(err, 'errr')
            }
        }

        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);

        const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();

        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

        socket.emit("call:accepted", { to: from, answer });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

socket.on('incoming:call', handleIncomingCall)

socket.addEventListener('connectedUsers', (data) => {
    console.log(data, 'connectedUsers')
})
```

Below I'm setting the answer in my remote desc after receiving it from the remote peer

```js
socket.on('call:accepted', async (data) => {
    const { answer, to } = data;
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    console.log('call accepted', answer);
});
```

please help me fix this problem I want to send a message to another peer and receive from him but I am not getting why no connection has been established even though I did everything well and all seems fine to me